# Instead of www.domain.org:8080/app I need www.domain.org. Apache2.2, Tomcat7, Debian7

Tags: apache-2.2, debian-wheezy, tomcat7

Instead of //servername.domain.org:8080/appdir. I need //servername.domain.org.

How is this done?  I want to truncate the URL dropping the :8080/appdir.

What's running on the server. Debian 7.8, Apache2.2, libapache2-mod-jk, Oracle's Java 7, Tomcat 7

Couple of documents I'm using as a guide.
apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html
digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps

Based on what I've read in the DigitalOcean doc I've been modifying the /sites/enabled/000-default file.

Here's my vhost.domain.org file.
/enabled sites/servername.domain.org

JkMount /* ajp13_worker
    ServerName servername.domain.org
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/
    ErrorLog /usr/share/tomcat/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /usr/share/tomcat/logs/access.log common
    
    Options -Indexes
    

 =======================================================================

I've tried this based on the "running different sites on different ports" from the Apache documentation.
And a couple of other iterations that didn't work.

Listen 80
Listen 8080

NameVirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80
NameVirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080

ServerName servername.domain.org
DocumentRoot /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/appdir

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

=============================================================================
/enabled sites/default-000 file in it's original form.

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: Check out mod_proxy in apache.

Answer (score 0):

The doc at this link provided a solution for me. 
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html
I added this line to apache2.conf.
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.mycompany.com/myapp/
Stopped and restarted Apache2.

Now when I key in the url www.mycompany.com it takes me straight to the app.